# Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet causing issue in xamarin.forms IOS

Tags: camera, xamarin.forms

Hello i have implemented camera functionality in my app using media.plugin
but camera does not open in ios.

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StorageFolder))
  {
                StorageFolder = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(SystemMessages.PhotoSaveFolder, "Cancel",
                null, "folder1", "folder2");

  }


  await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

  MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {

            });
```

it is because of DisplayActionSheet() which i use for folder option selection.if i remove that code it works fine.then what is issue with it.cant figure out.

it dont throw any error but thread exit after some time and in debugging i am unable to trace what exactly  going on.
please help.stuck with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add the right entrie(s) in the info.plist?

Comment: yes.i did.thats not an issue.and actually no issue in camera code.but DisplayActionList() is causing problem.it throws me out from there so  camera code is not executing.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: no.but  output window  shows thread exited .

Comment: did you try to execute the "await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();" call in the UI thread? Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize());  Maybe it can help ...

Comment: yes,i tried that too.no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh..that's the issue of xamarin version. i upgraded xamarin.forms from 2.3.0.107 to 2.3.4.247.that was causing issue.
revert back this changes solved my issue and working well as before.